# Handling Multiple GestureRecognizers

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer, skspritenode, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've run into an issue understanding `UIGestureRecognizers`. My goal right now is to have a set of GestureRecognizers to do different tasks, for example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    mainScene = GameScene(size: self.view.bounds.size)
    main = view as! SKView

    mainScene.panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(shiftView(recognizer:)))
    main.addGestureRecognizer(mainScene.panRecognizer)

    mainScene.tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(testTap(recognizer:)))
    main.addGestureRecognizer(mainScene.tapRecognizer)

    mainScene.pinchRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(zoomView(recognizer:)))
    main.addGestureRecognizer(mainScene.pinchRecognizer)
```

This is my game View Controller where I handle actions such as panning around a map, zooming, and tapping on map tiles. But I also want to be able to move sprites with a `UITapGestureRecognizer` so I also created this in my `GameScene`:

```
if startGame == true{
            self.startGame()
            for node in (self.tempGameBoard.landShipLayer.children as? Array<landship>)! {

                node.landShipInteraction = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(recognizer:)))
                parentViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(node.landShipInteraction)
            }
        }
```

The `landShip` in this case is representative of a sprite on screen that I would like to interact with via  gesture recognizers.

My issue is that if I add this second set of recognizers, the tapping action becomes completely unresponsive. I can still zoom and pan, but the tapping behaviors I expect on my map tiles do not occur. I feel as though I am missing some understanding of how the gesture recognizers work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` has a special function managing simultaneous recognition of several gestures on the same object, that will do the trick.

1) Set your `UIViewController` to conform `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

2) Implement the following function:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

    if (gestureRecognizer == mainScene.panRecognizer || gestureRecognizer == mainScene.pinchRecognizer) && otherGestureRecognizer == mainScene.tapRecognizer {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

In this particular example we allow the tap gesture to get triggered simultaneously with panning and pinching.

3) Then just assign the delegates to the pan and pinch gesture recognizers:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // your code...

    // Set gesture recognizers delegates
    mainScene.panRecognizer.delegate = self
    mainScene.pinchRecognizer.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, in step 2, that function means that the `panRecognizer and tapRecognizer` or the `pinchRecoginzer and tapRecognizer` can happen at the same time correct? And this will work the same way with two tapRecognizers?

Comment: @Aleksandr , it means that panning won't prevent tap recognition AND pinch won't do it as well. If you want to add any other tap recognizer object, you will need to add it to the function's condition manually. You can place some logging inside this function for better understanding of how it works.