# Unable to add two gesture to a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a UIView `sideMenuView` whose child is UIView `goToAccountButton`

```
let leftPanSwipe = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.sideMenuTranslate))
sideMenuView.addGestureRecognizer(leftPanSwipe)

let goToAccountGestureTap = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.goToAccountGesture))
goToAccountGestureTap.minimumPressDuration = 0.0
goToAccountButton.addGestureRecognizer(goToAccountGestureTap)
```

When trying to left swipe on `goToAccountButton` which is a child of `sideMenuView`, only `goToAccountGestureTap` works and it doesn't left-swipe at all.

I am unable to understand how to make both `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and  `UIPanGestureRecognizer` work on `goToAccountButton` as expected and so stuck. Please help me find a solution to this. Thank you.

Comment: Consider priority based implementation in your multi gesture environment. For more info see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/preferring_one_gesture_over_another

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272333/combine-longpress-gesture-and-drag-gesture-together

Comment: increase your minimumPressDuration to 1.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918256/handling-multiple-gesturerecognizers

Answer (score 0):

As @Ratul Sharker was hinting at, you need to make one of the gestures take priority. You probably want the pan to take priority, so add

```
goToAccountGestureTap.require(toFail: leftPanSwipe)
```

after you've set up the long-press gesture. This way, the long-press will only be checked for if the gesture isn't recognized as a pan gesture.

Comment: Mentioning this makes goToAccountGestureTap not work at all. How should I improve this?